# On Image hover, show image on top with lower opacity

Tags: html, css, image

I'm looking to have an image which when I hover it another image appears on top of it, but with a lower opacity, allowing the user to still be able to see the image behind it with this translucent image above it.

```
  <div id="wrapper"></div>

<style>
    #wrapper {
              width: 250px;
              height: 200px;
              background:url(https://33.media.tumblr.com/156ec9175fddca3df21443f7fd3bea28/tumblr_mjj09ad3NM1rmlyrqo1_1280.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#wrapper:hover {
              background:url(https://38.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_me1u8vETNC1rfliwho1_500.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
              opacity: .5;
}

</style>
```

this currently works, but I am not getting the opacity on the image which is displayed on hover.

Comment: That is because you are replacing the background image with the new one on hover, not overlaying it. You will need to create a separate element with this background image and place it above the original and toggle it's visibility / display / opacity on hover.

Comment: @nickspiel - Thank you. I realised that after posting this question, I have it working now. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

If you need both to be visible on `hover`, you can `blend` them this way:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/9qmdyuj0/3/)

```
#wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background:url(https://33.media.tumblr.com/156ec9175fddca3df21443f7fd3bea28/tumblr_mjj09ad3NM1rmlyrqo1_1280.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#wrapper:hover {
    background:url(https://38.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_me1u8vETNC1rfliwho1_500.gif),url(https://33.media.tumblr.com/156ec9175fddca3df21443f7fd3bea28/tumblr_mjj09ad3NM1rmlyrqo1_1280.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like @nickspiel said, you are replacing the background image with a new one. It makes more sense to have two images in the same div and change the opacity on hover. Like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="back" src="sample.jpg"/>
  <img class="front" src="sample2.jpg"/>
</div>
```

in the html and in the css:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.back, .front {
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}
.front{
  opacity: 0;
}
.container:hover .front {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

[Check out the Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/uhum1w2j/)